# RegEx in PHP: find the first matching string

Tags: php, regex

I want to find the first matching string in a very very long text. I know I can use preg_grep() and take the first element of the returned array. But it is not efficient to do it like that if I only need the first match (or I know there is exactly only one match in advance). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[preg_match()](http://www.php.net/preg_match) ?

> preg_match() returns the number of
>   times pattern matches. That will be
>   either 0 times (no match) or 1 time
>   because preg_match() will stop
>   searching after the first match.
>   preg_match_all() on the contrary will
>   continue until it reaches the end of
>   subject. preg_match() returns FALSE if
>   an error occurred.

Comment: But how can I extract the matching string then? Seems that by calling preg_match() I only know if there is match

Comment: The third argument to `preg_match()`, if given, will be filled with the match(es).

Comment: ahh..yes..why they don't just make it a separated function? easy to ignore.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
$string = 'A01B1/00asdqwe';
$pattern = '~^[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9]+~';

if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $match) ) {
  echo "We have matched: $match[0]\n";
} else {
  echo "Not matched\n";
}
```

You can try `print_r($match)` to check the array structure and test your regex.

Side note on regex:

- The tilde ~ in the regex are just delimiters needed to wrap around
  the pattern.
- The caret ^ denote that we are matching from the start
  of the string (optional)
- The plus + denotes that we can have one or
  more integers that follow. (So that *A01B1*, *A01B12*, *A01B123* will also
  be matched.