# get only second line with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex: `!^>{1} (.*)$!m` but I only want to match the second line here:

```
>> text1
> text2
> text3
```

but 3rd line is also matched here because of `m`. When I remove flag `m` it does only look at the beginning of the string, not start of line. `$` seems to do nothing at all.

see: https://regex101.com/r/AKYO1f/1

Comment: Just remove the `g` flag https://regex101.com/r/AKYO1f/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Shafizadeh said, just remove the `g` flag. This will make it return after the first match instead of finding ALL matches.

Just an explanation of why: When you have The multiline flag `^` and `&` match the beginning and end of a LINE but when you remove the multiline flag the `^` and `&` match the beginning and end of the STRING as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work.

Regex: `>{1,2}[\w\s]+\n\K\>[\s\w\d]+`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AKYO1f/3)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use preg_match()

> preg_match() returns the number of times pattern matches. That will be either 0 times (no match) or 1 time because preg_match() will stop searching after the first match. preg_match_all() on the contrary will continue until it reaches the end of subject. preg_match() returns FALSE if an error occurred.

The third argument to preg_match(), if given, will be filled with the match(es) inside an array

Got this from an answer at [RegEx in PHP: find the first matching string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709917/regex-in-php-find-the-first-matching-string)